# Зачем в пользовательском контроле поле components?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, usercontrol

При создании нового контрола студия всегда создаёт поле

```
private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

но никогда его не использует.

Для чего оно нужно?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069391/whats-the-purpose-of-the-components-icontainer-generated-by-the-winforms-design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На форму можно положить не только контролы, но и невизуальные компоненты. В то время как контролы при закрытии формы освобождаются автоматически, т.к. форма знает о своих дочерних контролах и прибивает их, компоненты этим свойством не обладают, и их надо закрывать явно. Для этого дизайнер создаёт переменную `components` и в перекрытом методе `Dispose()` прибивает компоненты, которые положены на форму.

Для того чтобы понять, чем недоволен компилятор, посмотрите на две вещи:
 1. Есть ли на форме невизуальные компоненты?
 2. Если есть, есть ли среди них компонент, конструктор которого принимает экземпляр `IContainer`. Правильно написанные компоненты должны иметь именно такой конструктор, который будет генерироваться дизайнером.

Answer (score 1):

Мой ответ может быть не очень точным.

На самом то деле используется, там хранятся ссылки на компоненты (потому что форма это контейнер) и при закрытии формы идет освобождение ресурсов (компонентов). Там в комментариях еще же написано: `Required designer variable`.

Comment: Раз используется, значит должная фигурировать в коде, но при компиляции я получаю варнинг "Полю components присвоено значение, но оно ни разу не использовано". Контрол не пустой.